# Try to send XMR to Bittrex

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

My wallet gives me with balance:

balance

Balance: 5.530000000000, unlocked balance: 5.530000000000

I feel confident, that a transfer of 5 XMR will cover the transaction fee.

At Bittrex, I learned my [Base Address] and [Payment ID]

I tried:

transfer 1 [Base Address] 5 [Payment_Id]

and keyed in my wallet password. I got an empty line as reply. Not sure, if that means WAIT, or if it means FAILED.

I tried then balance again, which shows me the initial answer.

With show_transferes I only see incoming XMRs.

Maybe I am just too impatient. How long do I need to wait? Am I using the right way to transfer and check the transaction?

Answer (score 3):

The instructions, simplified go like this (brackets indicate optional arguments):

`transfer [<priority>] [<ring_size>] <address> <amount> [<payment_id>]`

Your `transfer` command attempts a ring_size of 1. The default (and minimum) ring_size is 5.

If you want a priority of 1, it would be:

`transfer unimportant <address> <amount> <payment_id>`

Or, you would first `set priority 1` to make all transfers unimportant (low fee),

then `transfer <address> <amount> <payment_id>`